# Pagination does not work in Apollo React Native

Tags: react-native, graphql, pagination, apollo

My problem is that pagination for some reason does not work, most likely due to the fact that existing in this file = undefined

```js
import { FieldPolicy } from "@apollo/client/cache/inmemory/policies";
import unionBy from "lodash.unionby";
type KeyArgs = FieldPolicy<string>["keyArgs"];

export const cursorPagination = (
  keyArgs: KeyArgs = ["afterCursor"],
  unionByField = "__ref"
): FieldPolicy => ({
  keyArgs,
  merge(existing, incoming, { args }) {
    const incomingResult = incoming ? incoming.data : [];
    console.log("Incoming", incomingResult);
    const existingResult = existing ? existing.data : [];
    console.log("Existing", existingResult);
    const hasNextCursor = Boolean(args?.pagination?.afterCursor);
    if (hasNextCursor) {
      const resultPagination = unionBy(
        existingResult,
        incomingResult,
        unionByField
      );
      return {
        ...incoming,
        results: resultPagination,
      };
    }
    return incoming;
  },
});
```

Trying to understand why this is happening, I returned to my request, which is done as follows

```js
export const usePaginationPosts = () => {
  const [getPaginatedPosts, { data, fetchMore }] = usepostsLazyQuery({
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
  });

  const [afterCursor, setAfterCursor] =
    (useState < string) | null | (undefined > null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const getPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await getPaginatedPosts({
        variables: {
          input: { limit: 10, afterCursor: null, type: PostFilterType.New },
        },
      });
      setAfterCursor(response.data?.posts.pageInfo?.afterCursor);
      console.log(
        "response.data?.posts.pageInfo?.afterCursor",
        response.data?.posts.pageInfo?.afterCursor
      );
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, [getPosts]);

  const getMorePosts = useCallback(async () => {
    if (afterCursor) {
      const response = await fetchMore({
        variables: {
          input: { limit: 10, afterCursor, type: PostFilterType.New },
        },
      });
      setAfterCursor(response.data?.posts.pageInfo?.afterCursor);
    }
    console.log(afterCursor);
  }, []);

  return { isLoading, getPosts, getMorePosts, data };
};
```

My theory is that the problem is in afterCursor
Just in case, here is my cache option:

```js
export const cacheOption: InMemoryCacheConfig = {
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        posts: defaultCursorPagination,
        userMe: defaultCursorPagination,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

also query the request:

```
    query posts($input: FindPostsRequest!) {
      posts(input: $input) {
        data {
          author {
            firstName
            lastName
            avatarUrl
          }
          createdAt
          description
          id
          isLiked
          likesCount
          mediaUrl
          title
        }
        pageInfo {
          afterCursor
          count
          perPage
        }
      }
    }
```

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using `keyArgs` "the wrong way round" here.

The point of `keyArgs` is to say "if this argument is different, the underlying data does *not* belong together".

So the way you use it, each different `afterCursor` will be in a different cache entry and things will never merge together.

You would instead put something like `filters` in `keyArgs`, to prevent that listings with different filters would not end up in the same cache entry.